# Model Builder Error: Python cannot be found

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

Building some models in Model Builder for a training session, and it's not working out so well.  Model Builder can't seem to find Python.

Model Builder Error 000574: Python 2.7 is not installed

Here's the kicker...Not only am I looking at Python 2.7 as I type this, but I also ran a more complex model this morning.

Since the first issue this morning I have run a repair on ArcGIS 10.2 and installed Python again, since I was still receiving the same error after the repair.

Windows 7
Data source is read from Database Connection over the network and written locally. 
ArcGIS 10.2
Python 2.7.9
I've used several tools and datasets in the model. Both local and netowork sources.

[image: Error Message from Model Builder along with command line showing version]

[image: Very simple model. Verifies fine.]

[image: Python Window in ArcGIS. Commands not being recognized.]

Comment: Does Python work within the Python window in ArcMap?

Comment: My assumption earlier today was yes. But, as of now, I see that even though the window opens, it's not actually recognizing commands.  adding another screenshot to my original post...

Comment: Can you open windows command line and type python, what does it do? Not the python command line, but the windows one. Start Menu --> All Programs --> Accessories --> Command Prompt. Type python and hit enter, what does it do?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python installed? Is python 2.7 for ArcGis in your environment variable "PATH"? That error message will appear if it can't find python or if the version it finds is not 2.7.

Comment: Have a look at the section Paths and import in the help file [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Importing_ArcPy/002z00000008000000/).

Comment: 2.7.9 was installed during the reinstall. After much frustration last night and this morning, I have found that there is some sort of issue with Python on 64-bit machines. I'm in the process of working this angle. Keeping my fingers crossed that after a reboot everything will fall into place. To clarify, I have ditched 2.7.9 and reverted back. PATH variables are set. CMD line does pick up python. Picked up this during an image search of "Python27 ArcGIS": (http://pcigeomatics.github.io/PCI-Geomatics-Python-Cookbook/geomatica_cookbook_integrate_arcpy.html)

Comment: Is there somewhere within ArcMap that might store a path or hard coded environment variable to python? I've recreated my normal.mxt. I am very confused on how the command line works if I go to Start->ArcGIS->Python2.7 to open, but it's not found when opening directly from ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely wiping everything python and ArcMap related and doing an install from scratch worked. Once ArcMap and Python were uninstalled, I went back to the python folder and deleted it (there were some remnants left behind on uninstall) and removed all PATH variables that related to either.

Cause is still unknown. My assumption is that somehow something got corrupted (yesterday morning python worked in ArcMap, but a couple of hours later it did not) and was something that was skipped when doing a repair or reinstall while I had a copy of ArcGIS already on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that you have the following file:

`C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\desktop10.2.pth`

If you don't, open notepad as administrator and add these lines:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts
```

saving the file like you see above.

You'll also want to check your environment variables as mentioned in the comments, but after a Python reinstall, this is the first place to start.

Comment: I recreated this file, just in case. No luck. When I did the change in my comments above to ArcGISx6410.2, there is a DTBGGP64.pth that points to 64-bit locations, but no desktop10.2.pth.  I did attempt the 10.2 path, just to try it (changing the other to a .txt in the meantime, so there was no conflict), but there was no change.  Very confused by all of this. Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you `import arcpy` in the Python shell?

Comment: >>> import arcpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line
 21, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__in
it__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _base import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_bas
e.py", line 14, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>>

Comment: It reaches the arcpy folder, but seems to have a problem with arcpy.geoprocessing.

Comment: think you're bumping up against a 32vs64bit problem. did you install background geoprocessing specifically for troubleshooting this issue? if so, uninstall it and remove any path entries you made for it.

Comment: Yes--nothing seemed to really help. And I have already uninstalled it/removed paths to go back to the original setup.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which I hope it will work for you.

I have tried everything written in this post and python still was not working into my arcgis; giving the message 000574 error Python is not installed.

I have Win7 64 bit, and I was using Arcgis 9 then, installed Arcgis 10 and then, upgraded to 10.2 last three years, and in my last installation Python was not found by Arcgis. Also it was not working from python27.exe or pythonw.exe when I tried to run them from the folder C:\Python\Arcgis10.2.

However, I went at another computer where Arcgis 10.2 was recently installed and Python were running well. It was a Win7 32 bits but all was running fine. Then, I have checked out that python27.dll in my computer was different size (and also the creation date) than the python.dll installed in the other computer. Also, the date of the python.dll in my computer was older than the date I had installed Arcgis10.2. So, I discovered it was not replaced or updated with the last arcgis installations.

Then, I decided to remove the older python.dll file from my computer (located into System32 folder and syswow64 folder) and replace them with the newer file installed in the other computer. Also, I have pasted another copy of the new python.dll file into syswow32 just in case.

Everything started to work immediately when I opened ArcGis. I hope this could help to some of you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you erase the old python.dll file from system32 and syswow64 folders, (keep a copy of these files to revert the proces just in case) and then install again python from the installation dvd, this could fix your problem.
I took the python.dll file from the other computer were Argis+python were working fine, but if you don't have another computer with arcgis running, try to do what I say in the text above.
References:
-NOT WORKING python.dll ----->creation date 11/april/2012------->size 2918KB------> REMOVED
-WELL WORKING python.dll----->creation date 10/april/2012------->size 2250KB ----->PASTED TO SYSTEM32 FOLDER